# What is the use of w32api in minGW project

Tags: c, winapi, mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32

I have been reading about the minGW project and I am a bit confused about a specific part of it. If you look at http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW, the "Packages included with minGW" section mentions a `w32api` package. What is that?

Since the project was able to produce a Windows port of gcc, wouldn't you just have to link the Windows c library instead of glibc and have it work?

In the same document it explains:

> Header files and import libraries for the Microsoft Windows operating system

But doesn't Windows ALREADY provide header files and libraries for itself? Is the libc that minGW uses different from msvrct?

Comment: MinGW is dead, use mingw-w64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But doesn't Windows ALREADY provide header files and libraries for itself?

### No.

*Microsoft* provides a Windows SDK, which includes C header files, and import libraries for use in Visual Studio only. Other compiler vendors ship those headers (making any tweaks they may require to compile) and import libraries that are appropriate for use in their own compilers.

That is what the `w32api` package is for minGW.  The files needed to compile Windows code in minGW's environment.

Comment: An expansion of what Remy Lebeau
 said is that the SDK as shipped makes use of a large number of VC++ extensions to the core C alanguage. Some of these are understood by gcc and clang (the __declspec(dllimport) syntax as an example), others aare not (most other __declspec specifiers).

Comment: Yes, which may have to be wrapped with compiler-specific `#ifdef`'s to enable/disable them, or change their behavior, without having to rewrite large pieces of the headers.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir so what you are saying is that all/most "Microsoft extensions to c and c++" found here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx, would not be able to be compiled by gcc.... so what if I were to link the msvrct library to the compiler and ONLY use standard functions and common system calls? Would that work? I guess what I am getting at is, is there a specific thing other than extensions by microsoft/linux, that would tie a specific compiler to a specific libc implementation? Thank you.

Comment: Also thank you for your responses. I am still learning and very curious. Sometimes it's hard to find specific answers to specific questions that I have.